# How to have event unregister itself

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm using Grpc to cancel a long-running operation. I've set it up so that when the server receives the 'Cancel' command, it registers a task to the `SyncEnd` task so that it will return an answer when the long-running operation is *actually* cancelled.

Is there a way for me to have this event handler un-register itself when the job is done? If not, either the server crashes because the task has already completed, or I need to null out the event as the last action of the '`SyncEnd`' event (which I'm not sure is a great idea...I don't really want to have to re-register events every time the event is triggered)

What I have right now:

```
public override Task<CancelConfirm> CancelSync(CancelRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CancelConfirm>();
    Program.MyClass.SyncEnd += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(new CancelConfirm { Cancelled = true });
    };
    Program.MyClass.Cancel();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: `+=` to subscribe, `-=` to unsubscribe ?

Comment: @blaze_125 What would I put to the right of `-=`? And wouldn't that possibly de-register the event before it has a chance to fire?

Comment: Yes it would unregister, but you'd run that line only once the event is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegate to achieve the desired behavior.

```
public override Task<CancelConfirm> CancelSync(CancelRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CancelConfirm>();
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Program.MyClass.SyncEnd -= handler; //unregister itself
        tcs.SetResult(new CancelConfirm { Cancelled = true });
    };
    Program.MyClass.SyncEnd += handler; //
    Program.MyClass.Cancel();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the context of a `Button`

```
btn2.Click += Btn2_Click;//to register
btn2.Click -= Btn2_Click;//to unregister
```

Full snippet sample.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UnregisterEvent_46936409
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btn1.Location = new Point(5,5);
            txtbx.Location = new Point(5, btn1.Location.Y + btn1.Height + 2);
            this.Controls.Add(btn1);
            this.Controls.Add(txtbx);
            btn1.Click += (sender2, context2) => DoSomethingCool("put me in there", "yahoo");//subscribe to event handler
        }

        private void DoSomethingCool(string incoming1, string incoming2)
        {
            txtbx.Text = incoming1 + incoming2;
            btn1.Click -= (Sender2, context2) => DoSomethingCool("shouldnt do anything","blah blah");//unsubscribe from the event
        }
    }
}
```